# How to change the amount of data stored in pnp4nagios?

Tags: nagios, rrdtool

I installed pnp4nagios and all is fine, just want change a conf but not know how.

[Here](http://docs.pnp4nagios.org/pnp-0.6/doc_complete#storage) one can read

> Using the defaults allows to store the data with a resolution of one minute for the last two days, five minutes resolution for ten days, 30 minutes resolution for 90 days and 6 hours resolution for four years.

Where are such defaults and how change them to allows to store the data with a resolution of one minute for the last seven days?

Comment: How did you install it? distro package?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depends on your distribution but I think you want to look at the rra.cfg.

Change

```
 RRA:AVERAGE:0.5:1:2880
```

to

```
RRA:AVERAGE:0.5:1:10080
```

Please note this defines how much data is **stored**, the config.php is where the defaults are defined on how it's **displayed**. [Please see this page for more detail.](http://oss.oetiker.ch/rrdtool/doc/rrdcreate.en.html)

Comment: The file is `/usr/local/pnp4nagios/etc/rra.cfg` cos I installed *pnp4nagios* from sources. I saw several `RRA:AVERAGE` (`RRA:AVERAGE:0.5:5:2880 RRA:AVERAGE:0.5:30:4320 RRA:AVERAGE:0.5:360:5840`) and its corresponding `RRA:MAX` and `RRA:MIN` to the , I need change those values too? or just the `RRA:AVERAGE` I changed?

Comment: I believe this won't affect existing RRD files, but you can use rrdtool to tune/resize them (and verify that new ones are created correctly).

Comment: @Keith Hmm, what if I delete all file in `/usr/local/pnp4nagios/var/perfdata` ? I don't need keep all data cos I'm just starting the congiguration. BTW, @Keith do you know if I must change the others `RRA:` values?

Comment: @gsc-frank I think those values are for the min & max that get displayed under the graph so yes, you'd want the times to match up.

Comment: Anybody could sure me that? lol I will let this question open until tomorrow hopping that someone with deep knowledge about could take a look and explain me what values I must change. Thanks for your help @TheFiddlerWins

Comment: I thought I was clear but http://oss.oetiker.ch/rrdtool/doc/rrdcreate.en.html can help if you are confused. Each pnp4nagios image has a min and max listed over the time. The entries you are asking about is how they are determined.

Comment: Thanks @TheFiddlerWins I just was cautious cos your "I think" ;) Thanks again for your help.

Comment: Yes if you delete the old files, it will recreate new ones with the new settings. As long as you don't care about keeping old data, this is the easiest fix